# Why does \color fail in MaTeX?

Tags: functions, matex

Does anyone know why this fails? 
It worked before if I remember correctly.
(13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit))

```
  MaTeX[StringJoin["\\color{blue}", ToString@#], 
   "DisplayStyle" -> False] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]

(* out: {$Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed}*)
```

This is the error message which I didn't see as it was in a different window.

[image]

Comment: as xzczd mentioned, issue this command after loading matex `SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}"}]` but myself prefer the xcolor package (newer) so you can do `"\\usepackage{xcolor}"` instead

Comment: It doesn't just return `$Failed`. It show the error returned by LaTeX, which indicates what went wrong. Please include this error message in your question.

Comment: @Szabolcs it doesn't give any error message, just the output as I posted above.

Comment: @emnha That is not normal. Please open an issue on GitHub with detailed information about your system: MaTeX version, OS version, which TeX distribution (and which version) you are using, etc. https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/issues

Comment: This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8OJ5.png  If you could help figure out why the message is not issued on your system, that would be quite helpful. But discussing this in the comments here is difficult, hence my suggestion to do it on GitHub.

Comment: @Szabolcs I got the same error as yours in my laptop at home now. It didn't appear in my PC. I'll check that tomorrow as I don't have that PC here to reprocedure it.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry I got the same error as yours but because the error message window had opened before I excuted the command so I didn't notice it. 
If I closed the error message window and tried to execute the command again then the error message would popup.

Comment: @emnha Thanks for confirming that there is no issue with MaTeX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work you need to add

```
"Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color}"}
```

option to `MaTeX`. This is mentioned in **Options** ⊳ **"Preamble"** section of document of `MaTeX`.